# É obrigatório usar o decorador pyqtSlot?

Tags: python, pyqt

Quando quero conectar um `QPushButton`a um evento, por exemplo, utilizo um método e adiciono-o como callback do evento `clicked.connect`

Por exemplo:

```
def buildUi(self):

    self.buttonSubmitText  = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Enviar")

    self.textChat = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

    self.buttonSubmitText.clicked.connect(self.onSubmitText)



 def onSubmitText(self):

    text = self.textChat.text()

    message = create_message(self.selectedUser["id"], text)

    formattedText = self._buildChatText(message)

    self.viewChat.insertHtml(formattedText)

    self.textChat.setText("")
```

Porém tenho visto vários exemplos na internet onde é adicionado `QtCore.pyqtSlot()` como decorador. Ou seja, o código fica assim:

```
 @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
 def onSubmitText(self):

    text = self.textChat.text()

    message = create_message(self.selectedUser["id"], text)

    formattedText = self._buildChatText(message)

    self.viewChat.insertHtml(formattedText)

    self.textChat.setText("")
```

Eu gostaria de saber qual é o impacto de usar ou deixar de utilizar esse decorador? Isso faz alguma diferença?

É obrigatório usá-lo ou não?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme esta resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14431607/1518921), este [link](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) explica sobre o decorado (traduzido):

> Embora PyQt4 permita que qualquer coisa que pode ser chamado em Python (como métodos) seja usado como um `slot` ao conectar sinais, às vezes é necessário marcar explicitamente um método Python como sendo um `slot` Qt e fornecer uma assinatura [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) para ele. PyQt4 fornece o decorador `pyqtSlot()` de função para fazer isso.

E este outro trecho (traduzido):

> Ao conectar um sinal com um método com decorador tem a vantagem na redução do consumo de memória usado, sendo assim um pouco mais rápido.

Se não usar o decorador de `slots`, o mecanismo de conexão de sinal tem que calcular manualmente todas as conversões de tipo para mapear as assinaturas de função [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) para as funções Python, já quando os decoradores de `slots` são usados, o mapeamento de tipos podem ser explícitos.

Comment: Muito bom. Então vou usar em todos.